# can PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC hashing function cause an issue with special symbols like < or >?

Tags: pbkdf2

The PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC hashing function seems to fail when special symbols like < or > are used. It fails to give the the correct hash when such characters are used. Is it like the function is designed not to work with special characters?

Comment: To help any others, what did you find was the issue in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it like the function is designed not to work with special characters?

No.  PBKDF2 is a wrapper around HMAC, which is a wrapper around XOR and a hashing algorithm.  PBKDF2 and its dependencies are nothing but routine math, and operate, more or less, at the binary level.  You can feed any hexadecimal values you want, and it will function correctly.

Now, your code may be doing something strange in the conversions prior to calling PBKDF2, or whatever software and middleware and front end you are using may have issues.

To test:

- Print out the hexadecimal coded binary conversion of what you're trying to hash as well as the salt.  Examine this.
- If angle brackets in particular are an issue, do you have XML and/or HTML involved anywhere in the path between the human entering the data and your PBKDF2 function
- I have [several independent PBKDF2 implementations at my Github repository](https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords?tab=repositories), and in particular I've just finished upgrading the [OpenSSL library](https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords/PBKDF2-GCC-OpenSSL-library) version to support multiple input and output encodings.

  - Test that hexadecimal coded hash and hexadecimal coded salt against several of these implementations.
  - Test the test vectors in the above repositories against your code, beginning to end.
  - Test the test vectors in the above repositories against as close to the bare-metal PBKDF2 implementation you have as possible, skipping all the other code to the extent you can.